# The (Vector-)Constrained Least-Squares Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares

We got the following problem in class:

> Let $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$, $b\in\mathbb R^{m}$, $C\in\mathbb R^{p\times n}$ has independent rows and $d\in\text{im}\left(C\right) \subset \mathbb R^{p}$. Consider the minimization problem $$\min_{x\in \mathbb R^{n}}\frac{1}{2}\left\vert\left\vert Ax - b \right\vert\right\vert_{2}^{2} \quad \text{s.t.} \quad Cx = d. \qquad\qquad \left(\star\right)$$ Prove that a vector $\hat{x}\in\mathbb R^{n}$ solves $\left(\star\right)$ if and only if there exists $z\in\mathbb R^{p}$ s.t. $$\begin{pmatrix} A^{T}A & C^{T} \\ C & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \hat{x} \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} A^{T}b \\ d \end{pmatrix}.$$ Moreover, prove that the solution is uniquely defined if $\begin{pmatrix} A\\ C \end{pmatrix}$ has linearly independent columns.

My problem is with $"\Leftarrow"$, I managed $"\Rightarrow"$ with the help of Lagrange multipliers $\lambda$ and by setting $z:=-\lambda$. But for $"\Leftarrow"$, it's not quite clear how to "get rid" of $z$ and $C$, as they do not appear in $\left( \star\right)$. I mean, the matrix equation can be written as: $$A^{T}A\hat{x} + C^{T}z = A^{T}b, \qquad C\hat{x} = d.$$ I was now wondering whether I could simply integrate the two equations with respect to a vector and get a scalar, and even if it's possible, it is a priori not clear to me how to recover the constant $b^{T}b \in \mathbb R$ that we get from the norm-squared..

Comment: The result is obvious but I'm not sure how to give a good explanation, it depends on your background. Do you know about KKT conditions? What do you know about the Lagrangian? Why are you using it here?

Comment: @Khue Hi, to your questions: (i) I have heard about the KKT theorem, but doesn't it only apply to inequality constraints? (ii) I'm sorry, what do you mean by "what do you know about the Lagrangian"? Do you mean in our case, in general, ..? (iii) We have a minimization problem under a constraint, that's why I am using it here.. :)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I meant, how exactly were you taught to use the Lagrangian for solving a constrained optimization problem?

Comment: @Khue Ah, so let in our case $f(x) = \vert\vert Ax-b\vert\vert^2$ and $g(x) = Cx-d$, then consider the Lagrangian $\mathcal L(x, \lambda) = f(x)-\lambda^{T}g(x)$ and now solve for $\nabla \mathcal L = 0$.

Comment: Good. Do you know how to solve $\nabla L = 0$ in this case?

Comment: @Khue Yes, I get the matrix equation! But how to get from the matrix equation to the minimisation problem is rather unclear to me..

Comment: Right. I'm not sure what you have seen in class, but the theorem that tells you to solve $\nabla L = 0$ in order to find the optimal solutions to the original problem should also state that $\nabla L = 0$ is equivalent to the problem and thus the answer to the question follows immediately. Anyway, if the "$\Leftarrow$" part is what you get stuck at, then I'll show how it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need help on the "$\Leftarrow$" part, this is how it can be done.

Suppose that there exists $z\in\mathbb R^{p}$ satisfying
\begin{align}
A^TAx^* + C^Tz &= A^Tb\tag{1}\label{1}\\
Cx^* &= d\tag{2}\label{2}.
\end{align}

We need to show that $x^*$ solves $(\star)$, or equivalently
\begin{equation}
\|Ax-b\|_2^2 \ge \|Ax^*-b\|_2^2 \quad\mbox{for all } x \mbox{ such that } Cx=d.
\end{equation}
We know the equality will occur when $x=x^*$, so it is natural to decompose the LHS as
\begin{align}
\|Ax-b\|_2^2 &= \|Ax-Ax^* + Ax^* - b\|_2^2 \\
&= \|A(x-x^*)\|_2^2 + \|Ax^* - b\|_2^2 + 2(x-x^*)^TA^T(Ax^* - b).
\end{align}
The last term vanishes:
\begin{align}
(x-x^*)^TA^T(Ax^* - b) &= (x-x^*)^T(A^TAx^* - A^Tb)\\
&=-(x-x^*)^TC^Tz\\
&=-z^T(Cx-Cx^*)\\
&=0.
\end{align}
The conclusion follows.

---

By the way, you should view the original linear constraint as $d=Cx$ to have the Lagrangian $L(x,z) = f(x) + z^T(d-Cx)$, which helps avoid the change of variables $z=-\lambda$.

Comment: Hi Khue, cool, now that I look upon it, it seems very easy, and of course it makes sense to consider $\vert\vert Ax - b \vert\vert^{2}_{2} \geq \vert\vert 
Ax^{\star} - b \vert\vert_{2}^{2} \ \forall x: Cx = d$.. But I just didn't have this idea. I also was unsure about whether I am allowed to use for $\Leftarrow$ that $Cx = d$ (I thought we only know $C\hat{x} = d$), but looking at your answer, I guess we do know that we have a constraint of this form. :)

Comment: Actually, I would have another question concerning another minimization problem, but this time about kernel-based approximations with a native kernel space $\mathcal F$. Would you be willing to help out here as well, or am I asking too much of you? :) I would like to think a bit more, I could try to post sth at the very latest by tomorrow night..

Comment: @Hermi Unfortunately I'm not sure I'll be available over the next few days, but feel free to post your questions, there are many smart people on this site. (If it's homework then ask for hints, for your own sake.)